# Client-Server not sending the entire file

Tags: java, file, client

When I run my client server - which is connecting and I try to send a file it doesn't won't send the whole file which is pulling errors else where, it gets about halfway through and constantly stops at the same part. This set up works when running the server-client on the same machine so I am completely confused

Server --->

```
    // output (a DataOutputstream) is set up elsewhere and messages are sent and received properly
    output.writeInt((int)file.length());
    // send file

    byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)file.length()];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
    System.out.println("Sending " + file + "(" + mybytearray.length + " bytes)");
    output.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
    output.flush();
    System.out.println("Done.");
```

Client --->

```
            // input (a DataInputstream) is set up elsewhere and messages are sent and received properly
            String FILE_TO_RECEIVED = "Load_From.xml";
            File file = new File(FILE_TO_RECEIVED);

            int FILE_SIZE = input.readInt();
            if(FILE_SIZE!=0){
                // receive file
                System.out.println("received file size : " + FILE_SIZE);
                byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [FILE_SIZE];
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                int bytesRead = input.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
```

Comment: Where does it stop? Does it work with small files (say, 2KB)?

Answer (score 2):

You are only reading part of the data, both when reading the file and when reading the socket. The `read` method returns the number of bytes read, and you need a loop to read everything. For example,

```
int read = 0, offset = 0;
while ((read = bis.read(mybytearray, offset, mybytearray.length - offset) != -1) {
    offset += read;
}
```

Or you can use classes from the standard library, for example `DataInputStream` has a `readFully` method.

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
dis.readFully(mybytearray);
```

Comment: If I use dis.readFully(mybytearray) how do I turn that into a file?

Comment: All you have to do is write the bytes into a file. The code you have for that already looks OK.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the documentation of `read()` at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int).

In particular:

> An attempt is made to read as many as len bytes, but a smaller number may be read. The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer.

This means that if the length returned is not what you expect and you haven't encountered the end of file yet, you should call read() again (in a loop).